# How come do resistors lower the current of the whole circuit but the current is the same before and after a resistor?

Tags: electric-circuits, electrical-resistance, electronics

Thats what I understood from articles on the internet. I just cant wrap my head around it, can someone explain it to me?

Comment: As you wrote: it lowers the current of the *whole* (of that part) of the circuit. Where there are no junctions, the current is the same at every point, and so it doesn't matter where you measure it.

Comment: @ThomasFritsch that was a helpful link :) Now I understand it better, thank you so much! Have a great day